# Как проверить, существует ли какой-нибудь определённый символ в строке?

Tags: c++

Например, узнать существует ли символ @ в введённой строке, и написать "YES" или "NO"

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std; 

int main() { 
    string stroka; 
    cin >> stroka; 
    if ((stroka.find('@')) < 20) 
        cout << "YES"; 
    else cout << "NO";
```

Comment: Ну и, у вас есть какие-нибудь мысли? Уже попробовали что-то написать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 
 string stroka;
 cin >> stroka;
 if ((stroka.find('@')) < 20) cout << "YES"; else cout << "NO";

Comment: Пожалуйста добавьте этот код в вопрос, нажав на кнопку "Править" под вопросом. А так же напишите что не так с вашим кодом.

Comment: Хорошо, код у вас есть. Объясните, что с ним не так. Он не работает?

Comment: нет, я просто хотел спросить, нет ли другого способа для поиска символа?

Comment: Конечно, есть - правильно использовать `find` - прочтите о нем здесь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: Может и есть другие способы, но это самый лучший (по крайней мере лично я лучше не знаю) способ. Но вы пишите `if((stroka.find('@')) < 20)` это условие будет возвращать `true` когда индекс первого вхождения '@' будет < 20. [Функция find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) возвращает `string::npos` если символ в строке не найден, иначе возвращает индекс первого вхождения переданного в него символа. `if(stroka.find('@') != string::npos)` будет правильней писать.

Answer (score 3):

Для `string s` -

```
if (s.find('@') != s.npos) // Символ есть
```

Для char `s[]` -

```
if(strchr(s,'@')) // Символ есть
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать в качестве сравнения в условии такое выражение string::npos, оно возвращается если метод find ничего не нашел

Answer (score 1):

Можно по-другому проверить есть ли символ в массиве:
Допишите
#include cstring  - библиотека для string
#include cstdlib - библиотека для массивов

```
SetCosoleCP(1251);
SetConSoleOutputCP(1251); // код кирилицы

string* arr[20];
cout << "Введите строку из 20ти символов без пробелов, или используйте _ вместо пробела " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i] ;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    cout << "/t" << arr;
}
char n;
cout << "Введите символ, который вы хотите проверить - ";
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == n)
    {
        cout << "true" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "false" << endl;
    }
}
```

или ещё проще:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 20; i++){
    if(arr[i] == '@')
    {
        cout << "true" << endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "false" << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: `string.h` это стандартная библиотека си, для с++ нужно использовать `cstring`